# Recurrence of $k$-step ahead forecast with ARMA

Tags: time-series, self-study, mathematical-statistics, forecasting, arima

For brevity, let's consider an AR(1) model, but this question should apply to ARMA(p, q) in general. Assume we are at time $T$ and would like to forecast $k$ steps ahead,

$$
X_{T+k} = \phi_0 + \phi_1 X_{T+k-1} + \epsilon_{T+k}
$$

It is known that the optimal $k$-step ahead forecast $\hat{X}_{T+k}$ (which is a function of $I_T$) that will minimize the mean square error is

$$
\hat{X}_{T+k|T} = E(X_{T+k}|I_{T})
$$

According to my professor,

$$
\hat{X}_{T+k|T} \color{red}{=} \phi_0 + \phi_1 \hat{X}_{T+k-1|T}
$$

Let $k \to \infty$, then

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{k \to \infty} \hat{X}_{T+k | T} &= \lim_{k \to \infty} \left(\phi_0 + \phi_1 \hat{X}_{T+k-1 | T}\right) \\
&= \phi_0 + \phi_1 \lim_{k \to \infty} \hat{X}_{T+k-1 | T} \\
&= \phi_0 + \phi_1 \lim_{k \to \infty} \hat{X}_{T+k | T} \\
\lim_{k \to \infty} \hat{X}_{T+k | T} &= \frac{\phi_0}{1-\phi_1}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

However, she also stated that as $k$ approaches infinity, $\hat{X}_{T+k|T}$ should "recur" to $\phi_0$. This appears to be a contradiction. Thus, I suspect the red equality sign above is incorrect, isn't it? If I'm right, what's the correct formula?

Comment: I think the equality is correct and there is no contradiction, because what happens in the limit need not coincide with what happens one step ahead (the red equality considers $X$s that are only one step apart).

Comment: @RichardHard You mean the equality sign no longer holds when I take limit on both sides of the formula? Please note that the limit is not taken on the number of steps appear; it's taken on $k$ instead. $T+k$ and $T+k-1$ is always one step apart regardless of how big $k$ is.

Comment: I just noticed that the penultimate equation has $\hat X_{T+k}$ instead of $\hat X_{T+k-1}$ on the right side, which makes it different from the preceding equation. Is that intentional? Also, I now see why the red equality is incorrect: the information set $I_t$ does not include $\hat X_{T+k-1}$, so we cannot use it to express $\mathbb{E}(\hat X_{T+k}|I_T)$.

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes, it is! The reason is the same as the one behind $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$ = $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n-1}$.

Comment: OK, I thought so. You just skipped this step, but that does not invalidate the equality. Right.

Comment: @RichardHardy Regarding your second point above, while $I_t$ does not include $X_{T+k-1}$, we can estimate it with $\hat{X}_{T+k-1}$, which is a function of $I_t$. Actually, I suppose $\forall k$, $\hat{X}_{T+k} = E(X_{T+k}|I_T)$ is a function of $I_T$.

Comment: It is not obvious from the notation whether $\hat X_{T+k-1}$ is a function of $I_t$, but it could be clearer if you wrote $\hat X_{T+k-1|T}$. Then your last point would make sense. But then it would be even clearer to write explicitly what $\hat X_{T+k-1|T}$ is in terms of elements of $I_t$.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my question to clarify!

Comment: This is not exactly what I meant. I think you should unroll the recursion so as not to use anything with time index above $T$ on the right hand side (at least in the expression with the limits).

Comment: @RichardHardy I'm sorry but I didn't get you. Feel free to edit my post if you feel like it, though.

Comment: I mean spelling out what $\hat X_{T+k|T}$ is:$\hat X_{T+k|T}=\phi_0+\phi_1\hat X_{T+k-1|T}=\phi_0+\phi_1\(\phi_0+\phi_1\hat X_{T+k-2|T})=\dots$ until you hit $\hat X_{T|T}$ which is $X_{T}$.

Comment: I'm sure what she meant is that the forecast should recur to the stationary mean of the process $\mu= \phi_0/(1-\phi_1)$ and not to $\phi_0$.  There is then no contradiction.

Comment: Wow, I think I had overlooked yet another bit: there is indeed $\phi_0$ rather than $\phi_0/(1-\phi_1)$ in the last paragraph...